# Unable to unbind/disable the built-in USB driver

Tags: raspbian, debian, driver, device-tree

i was trying to upload my custom USB driver to test it but the kernel calls it's built-in USB driver probe once pendrive is plugged in.

1)i cannot directly remove using the built-in drive functn. as it denies permission.

sudo rmmod usb_storage -> rmmod: ERROR: Module usb_storage is builtin.

2)Tried unbinding the usb dev my-usb.rules file - "SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0781", ATTR{idProduct}=="5567", MODE="0666", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo -n %k > /sys%p/unbind'" and reloading the rules but it didn't work.

is there any way to disable built-in drivers and upload custom drivers to test? i guess i'll face the same problem for other devices as well.

device/kernel - raspberry pi4 / Linux raspberrypi 6.1.0-rpi7-rpi-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian